# Difference between dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0,0,rc1-final and dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0,0.rc1-update1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. However despite selecting install Web Applications it wasn't installed. I then installed from the [get.asp.net](http://get.asp.net) website the installer asp.net 5 RC.

Now when I want to open my `ASP.net 5` project I get this message:

[image]

How do I know which one is the latest version?
dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0,0,rc1-final and dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0,0.rc1-update1

and how do I upgrade my existing project to use the latest one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latest version is the update-1. There was not a lot of communication about it, but you can safely upgrade your projects to it, you don't need rc1-final anymore, unless you specifically want it.

The easiest way to do this is simply right-click on your project, Properties and  selecting which dnx version you want to use. Clicking No should also have this effect.

[image]

[Some more info](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1151)

Comment: When I right click on my project, it only mentions the .net framework version e.g. dnx451. Only place where a reference the dnx version I could find rc1 or update-1 shows is the publishing options

Comment: @devc2 I forgot to mention that you should click properties. It should show something like above:

Answer (score 5):

rc1-update1 was released a couple of weeks after rc1, due to some installer/dnx issues.  An update was appended to the [official rc1 release announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1.aspx).

> The ASP.NET 5 RC1 installers and DNX packages have been updated to
>   address the following issues:
>
> - If you run the Windows installer from a folder that contains previous versions of the MSI installers for DNVM
>     (DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi or DotNetVersionManager-x86.msi) or the
>     ASP.NET tools for Visual Studio (WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi or
>     WebToolsExtensionsVWD14.msi), the installer will fail with an error
>     “0x80091007 - The hash value is not correct”.
> - When installing on OS X the .pkg installer would create the ~/.dnx folder on a clean machine as root so you couldn’t do anything
>     involving that folder unless you were root
>     ([aspnet/dnx#3191](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3191))
> - Running a published .NET Core based application results in FileNotFoundExceptions for missing assemblies (ex.
>     System.Net.Security, System.Data.SqlClient)
>     ([aspnet/dnx#3183](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3183))
>
> The updated version of DNX (1.0.0-rc1-update1) is available via the
>   .NET Version Manager (DNVM). **Note, no other ASP.NET 5 NuGet packages
>   are affected by this update and thus their versions remain unchanged.**
>   If you have already installed RC1 please acquire and run the installer
>   again from http://get.asp.net to get this update.